# Getting error "operation is not allowed when the object is closed" error. Looking for a solution

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

Every time I run my vba file, I get the run time error 3704, Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.  Trying to fix this error.

Messed around with connection types and other parameter types, but to no avail.  The goal of the code is to be a front end means for business to enter data into a SQL database.  Business does not want to have to leave excel for this.  The stored proc called in the vba code inputs data into a SQL database. I've verified the stored proc works in SQL.  The goal of the vba code is to call the stored proc and import the data to the sql database.  I've done this with a test DB and one var.  Now I have 27.  Trying to find the error.

There are 27 vars, I did not include all of them.  I verified they all pull the correct data from excel.  I have also had others verify that the params are the correct params in SQL.

```
Sub ImportProForma()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlCommand As ADODB.Command, PKprm As Object

Dim PK As Integer
PK = Range("D3").Value

Sheets("UpdateProForma").Select
Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
cnSQL.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security = sspi; Initial Catalog = [Database]; Data Source = [Server]"

Set sqlCommand = New ADODB.Command
sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = cnSQL
sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

sqlCommand.CommandText = "ImportNewEntry"

Set PKprm = sqlCommand.CreateParameter("PrimaryKey", adInteger, adParamInput)
PKprm.Value = PK

sqlCommand.Parameters.Append PKprm
sqlCommand.Parameters("PrimaryKey") = PK


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open sqlCommand

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

The final goal of this project is to be able to import data to SQL without having to have business leave excel.

Comment: Does your stored procedure return any records?  If not then you don't need a recordset.  Might also help to mention which line produces the error.

Comment: Have you tried `unload rs` instead of `rs.Close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included record sets in the code despite there being no data imported into excel.  After Tim Williams (user:478884) pointed out that I did not require a record set.  I removed the rs and other unnecessary code.  Code now reads:

```
Sub ImportProForma()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlCommand As ADODB.Command, PKprm As Object

Dim PK As Integer
PK = Range("D3").Value

Sheets("UpdateProForma").Select
Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
cnSQL.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security = sspi; Initial Catalog = [Database]; Data Source = [Server]"

Set sqlCommand = New ADODB.Command
sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = cnSQL
sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
sqlCommand.CommandText = "ImportNewEntry"

Set PKprm = sqlCommand.CreateParameter("PrimaryKey", adInteger, adParamInput)
PKprm.Value = PK

sqlCommand.Parameters.Append PKprm
sqlCommand.Parameters("PrimaryKey") = PK

sqlCommand.Execute
Cells.Range("D5:D55").ClearContents

End Sub
```

I do not clear the data in D3 for PK, I have a vba function that auto increments the Primary Key.